# MySQL Union distinct based on equality predicate

Tags: mysql, union

I have two tables which have columns "name" "lname" "val" and I want their union so that "name" and "lname" are unique with the first table overriding the rows of the second. Union distinct looks like what I want but I cant make it check only the first two rows.

Comment: Are `name, lname` unique each of the two tables separately? If not, which of the `val` do you want to be returned?

Comment: What does your tables look like, and can you state your desired output? and btw UNION is a set operator so the `distinct` would be redundant writing, but can be included for improved readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select a.name, a.lname, a.val from a)
union
(select b.name, b.lname, b.val from b left join a using(name, lname) where a.name is null)
```